# Kilograms to grams convert processor in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

There is a standard processor/converter for bytes from gigabytes https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bytes-processor.html

We have a field `weight` and the values can be `3kg`, `1200g`, ...

Is there similar processor for grams? Or which processor can be used to achieve same functionality?

Comment: You can easily write your custom processor using the [`script` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/script-processor.html)

Comment: @Val can you please help how this script should look like?